# Not all XEN VMs auto start after reboot of DOM 0

Tags: xen

On my Xen host (systemd in Debian Buster, Xen 4.11), I usually start all guest VMs automatically. I added all my VM configs as link in `/etc/xen/auto/` to the underlying config like

```
/etc/xen/auto/proxy.cfg -> /etc/xen/proxy.cfg
/etc/xen/auto/vm04.matrix.cfg -> /etc/xen/vm04.matrix.cfg
...
```

and sometimes some guest VMs start automatically on reboot of the DOM0 host and sometimes some fail and throw these errors in syslog:

```
$ grep "Starting Xen domain" /var/log/syslog
May 12 08:38:36 dom0 xendomains[1103]: Starting Xen domain proxy (from /etc/xen/auto/proxy.cfg)...done.
May 12 08:38:36 dom0 xendomains[1103]: Starting Xen domain vm04.matrix.de (from /etc/xen/auto/vm04.matrix.cfg)...failed.
```

If they fail, the errors in `\var\log\syslog` around the fail during boot are:

```
Starting Xen domain vm04.matrix (from /etc/xen/auto/vm04.matrix.cfg)...failed.
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:417:libxl__device_disk_set_backend: Disk vdev=xvda2 failed to stat: /dev/vg0/vm04.matrix-disk: No such file or directory
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:983:initiate_domain_create: Domain 4:Unable to set disk defaults for disk 0
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1034:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 4:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:993:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 4:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:920:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 4:Destruction of domain failed

---

Starting Xen domain proxy (from /etc/xen/auto/proxy.cfg)...failed.
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:417:libxl__device_disk_set_backend: Disk vdev=xvda2 failed to stat: /dev/vg0/proxy-disk: No such file or directory
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:983:initiate_domain_create: Domain 1:Unable to set disk defaults for disk 0
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1034:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 1:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:993:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 1:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:920:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 1:Destruction of domain failed
```

The files `/etc/xen/proxy.cfg` and `/etc/xen/vm04.matrix.cfg` are identical apart from the mount-points.

If I start `xen create /etc/xen/vm04.matrix.cfg` later manually it starts just fine, only not automatically during the boot of the host.

### debugging

To debug the problem, I added this in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=4096M,max:4096M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all"
```

and called `update-grub`, but after a reboot the error messages in syslog are the same. I cannot find anything suspicious in `dmesg` either. No mentions of any of the guest hostnames. Only this shows, the problem:

```
# dmesg|grep dev|tail
[   11.348931] xen:xen_evtchn: Event-channel device installed
[   22.006020] device vif3.0 entered promiscuous mode
[   25.362878] device vif5.0 entered promiscuous mode
[   28.636912] device vif6.0 entered promiscuous mode
[ 1004.501654] device vif7.0 entered promiscuous mode
...
```

You only see, that the first three VMs Network-interfaces did start during boot this time and 1000s later I started the next VM manually on the console.

Xen loads just fine:

```
$ systemctl --type=service | grep -i xen
xen.service                        loaded active running LSB: Xen daemons                                                             
xendomains.service                 loaded active running LSB: Start/stop secondary xen domains
```

I think the best hint to the problem is that the volume is not there during boot:

```
/dev/vg0/proxy-disk: No such file or directory
```

maybe xen starts too early in the boot process?

```
systemctl cat xen.service|uniq
# /run/systemd/generator.late/xen.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/xen
Description=LSB: Xen daemons
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/xen start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/xen stop
```

```
systemctl cat xendomains.service|uniq
# /run/systemd/generator.late/xendomains.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/xendomains
Description=LSB: Start/stop secondary xen domains
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
Before=corosync.service
Before=heartbeat.service
Before=libvirtd.service
After=network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=xen.service
After=drbd.service
After=iscsi.service
After=openvswitch-switch.service
After=nfs-kernel-server.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/xendomains start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/xendomains stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/xendomains reload
```

How can I further debug this?

Comment: could you please check with `xl -vvvv` to have more logs?

Comment: How can I call that during boot?

Comment: I added the service details, what is the `TimeoutSec=5min` referring to? maybe that is a problem, because a reboot of the mashine takes about 10minutes due to unknown reasons (i cannot see the console)

Comment: well, we can debug with `journalctl -xb` to see what happens during boot and also please check `journalctl -u xen.service` to investigate errors related to this service. `TimeoutSec=`: amount of time systemd will wait when stopping or starting the service before marking it as failed or forcefully killing it. We can make it `infinity` or restart on failure. lets first check if we can have more debug logs or not.

Comment: those journalctl commands don't show anything new, the same as in syslog already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workaround

If there is no solution to put the starting of all VMs, you can create a new script, that checks all configs in /etc/xen/auto and starts them manually if not started.

### 1. create a file `/usr/local/sbin/xen-start-all-auto`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/xen/auto/

for x in *; do
 d=$(echo $x|sed 's/.cfg$//g')
 echo check $d ...
 lvs|grep $d-disk|grep -v snap|grep -q -- '-ao'
 if [ $? == 1 ]; then
   xen create $x
 else
   echo ok
 fi
done
```

and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/xen-start-all-auto
```

### 2. create a systemd service that starts once

create a file `/etc/systemd/system/xen-autostart.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=starts all XEN vms in /etc/xen/auto if they are not started already 1 minute after system start

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/xen-start-all-auto

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

## Update systemd with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable xen-autostart
systemctl start xen-autostart &
```

Comment: Maybe interested of the bash script, this command would be enough: `systemctl restart xendomains`

Comment: no, `systemctl restart xendomains` also just starts the same "some" VMs

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `xendomains.service` might be starting too early, before all the logical volumes in `vg0` are activated. You might have to add/change some dependencies to as appropriate to your system configuration.

The current configuration is causing `xendomains.service` and thus the VMs to attempt starting *before* cluster components like `corosync.service` and `heartbeat.service` and VM management service `libvirtd.service`. If your `vg0` is a clustered volume group that requires these cluster component services before it can activate, you should change `xendomains.service` to start `After` them, not `Before`.

And since `libvirtd` is the server-side daemon that actually handles starting and stopping other VMs, the attempt to start other VMs should probably happen only after `libvirtd.service` is started.

`systemctl edit xendomains.service` should open an empty temporary file in your designated editor, which will then automatically become an override file for the `xendomains.service` unit: `/etc/systemd/system/xendomains.service.d/override.conf` or something similar.

But the man page `systemd.unit(5)` says:

> Dependencies (`After=`, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty list, so dependencies can only be added in drop-ins. If you want to remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit.

So creating an override file won't work here. Instead, you would need to copy the existing auto-generated unit file to `/etc/systemd/system/xendomains.service`:

```
systemctl cat xendomains.service | uniq >/etc/systemd/system/xendomains.service
```

Then you can edit `/etc/systemd/system/xendomains.service` using your favorite editor, and finally run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make the changes effective. You should edit the list of dependencies to look like this:

```
[...the lines before this should be left as is...]
Description=LSB: Start/stop secondary xen domains
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=corosync.service
After=heartbeat.service
After=libvirtd.service
After=network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=xen.service
After=drbd.service
After=iscsi.service
After=openvswitch-switch.service
After=nfs-kernel-server.service
Wants=network-online.target
[...the lines after this should be left as is...]
```

Comment: @rubo77 these systemd scripts have been generated automatically by `systemd-sysv-generator` as you can see there are 3 same lines of `Before=multi-user.target`. Also please provide `systemctl cat xendomains.service` maybe we need to tune the dependencies.

Comment: @rubo77 Please see my edit. If `systemctl edit xendomains.service` opens an editor with an empty file, it's actually doing what it's generally supposed to do. But in this case, you'll need to override the entire autogenerated unit file so that you can remove the unwanted `Before=` dependencies.

Comment: I tried the override, but after a reboot now it sais: `# systemctl status xendomains.service
● xendomains.service - LSB: Start/stop secondary xen domains
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/xendomains; static; vendor preset: enabled)                                                                                                                                                         
   Active: inactive (dead)` it seems like it never started

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is available in 4.11 I know in 6 it is:

```
xe pool-param-set uuid=UUID other-config:auto_poweron=true
```

When you do a "xe vm-list" that will give you the UUIDs.

Comment: I get `xe: command not found
`

Comment: it is called `xen` in my system: `xen vm-list |
UUID                                  ID    name |
d79abc4c-2ab0-4679-9435-b0001dca406b  24    proxy ` ... but there is no `xen pool-param-set` in xen 4.11